# Selecting from type-based DbSet using .Set() instead of .Set<T>()

Tags: entity-framework-6, dbset

I am creating an advanced search that converts an OData expression into a .NET expression tree (`Expression<Func<T, bool>>`).  I pass this expression into my EF6 .Select() method as a predicate and it works as expected.

However, in implementing this feature, I've discovered that LINQ methods only work with `IQueryable<TSource>`.  This works for `.Set<T>()`, but I won't know the type at runtime, so I need to use `.Set()`.

I could probably use reflection to call `.Set<T>()` and then invoke it, but that seems like a bit of a hack, so I'd rather do it directly through `.Set()` if at all possible.

Comment: How do you create `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` if you don't know `T`?

Comment: @IvanStoev You can create expressions using types.

Comment: Like non generic `Expression.Lambda` that returns `LambdaExpression`? And you want to bind it to `Where`?

Comment: @IvanStoev Correct.  I want to take the resulting lamba and pass it right into LINQ's .Select() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have `LambdaExpression` instead of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and you want to use it as `Where` but on `IQueryable` (which `DbSet` class implements) rather than `IQueryable<T>`.

All you need to know is that `IQueryable<T>` extensions methods simply emit `MethodCallExpression` to the corresponding `Queryable` method in the query expression tree.

For instance, to emulate `Where` or `Select` on `IQueryable` you can use the following custom extension methods:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, LambdaExpression predicate)
    {
        var expression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Where",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);
    }

    public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source, LambdaExpression selector)
    {
        var expression = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Select",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType, selector.Body.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);
    }
}
```

You can do similar for other `Queryable` methods needed.

**Update:** Since you are interesting in, here is an example of using expression prototypes to get a generic method definition and construct generic method from it:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    static MethodInfo QueryableMethod<T>(this Expression<Func<IQueryable<object>, T>> prototype, params Type[] types)
    {
        return ((MethodCallExpression)prototype.Body).Method
            .GetGenericMethodDefinition()
            .MakeGenericMethod(types);
    }

    public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, LambdaExpression predicate)
    {
        var expression = Expression.Call(
            QueryableMethod(q => q.Where(x => true), source.ElementType),
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(predicate));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);
    }

    public static IQueryable Select(this IQueryable source, LambdaExpression selector)
    {
        var expression = Expression.Call(
            QueryableMethod(q => q.Select(x => 1), source.ElementType, selector.Body.Type),
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery(expression);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's awesome.  Works perfectly.  Any idea how to get the MethodInfo of the LINQ methods using expressions so you don't have to use a string?  I tried for a couple hours, but got hung up on matching the overloads' signatures that use generic types (usually, you can just pass a default type, but I don't know how to do it with generics).

Comment: Why bother with MethodInfo - the names of the methods will not change, and also if you are on C#6 you could always use `nameof(Queryable.Select)`

Comment: I swear I tried nameof, but it was giving me some issues.  Just tried it again and it works, so I was doing something wrong.  Agreed, the names will never change, but I tend to avoid magic strings wherever possible.  Thanks again

Comment: No problem. See the update for a way to accomplish what you asked in the first comment :) Cheers.